# Convolution between bit stream sampled by N number of samples per bit with a channel modeled as low pass filter

Tags: convolution, finite-impulse-response, lowpass-filter, z-transform, digital-filters

I generated a bit stream in MATLAB, from the transmitter to be convoluted by the channel

I use MATLAB function "randi" between 0 & 1, so it generates random vectors of 0s & 1s and connects them to produce triangles

I want to make N (e.g N=4) samples per bit, so each bit is produced contains 4 samples for example 1 0 1 0 1 >>> 1111 0000 1111 0000 1111

I model channel as Low Pass Filter e.g h = [0.2 0.3 0.4]

How can I convolute the bit stream with the channel ?

Before, it was done by 1*0.4 + 0*0.3 + 1*0.2 , next time instant will take new bit as 0*0.4 + 1*0.3 + 0*0.2  and so on

Now, The 1 1 1 1 multiplied with 0.4 and then 0000 multiplied with 0.3, so how the output will be generated serially, the addition of what will generate the output at a time instant

How the output will be generated ?
Is there a function in MATLAB to do this convolution with determining samples per bit ?

Comment: "connects them to produce triangles": um, why that? That feels like nothing a real system would do. What is your motivation behind this kind of interpolation? Or are you just plotting it like this? Remember to make a distinction between your actual digital signal and the way you plot it, in that case (the straight lines between samples are not correct.)!

Comment: you don't convolve bits, you convolve symbols (which can happen to be 0 or 1, but it's unusual, and probably not what you wanted or should do). Do you know which *constellation* you're supposed to be using?

Comment: Why would N=4 lead to 4 *repetitions*? That's not how you upsample!